# Dividing 2d array of size (256, 256) into block size of 8X8

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

So I have a 256 X 256 array. and am trying to perform an action on each 8X8 block
So far I have this code

```
for i in range(32):

    # Compute start row index of the block
    row_ind_1 = i % nbh
    
    # Compute end row index of the block
    row_ind_2 = (i + block_size) % nbh
    
    for j in range(32):
        
        # Compute start column index of the block
        col_ind_1 = j % nbw

        # Compute end column index of the block
        col_ind_2 = (j + block_size) % nbw

        # # select the current block we want to process using calculated indices
        block = padded_img[ row_ind_1 : row_ind_2 , col_ind_1 : col_ind_2 ]
```

But this is not working. Can someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this may not be the most optimal way to do this but here is a possible solution if you don't want to use any libraries.

```py
for i in range(32):
    row_s = 8 * i
    row_e = 8 * (i + 1)
    for j in range(32):
        col_s = 8 * j
        col_e = 8 * (j + 1)
        temp_block = padded_img[row_s : row_e]
        block = [temp_block[k][col_s:col_e] for k in range(len(temp_block))]
```

I would recommend looking at numpy though cause there are much easier ways to do it with that library.
link: https://numpy.org

Comment: thanks. I would try looking at a way to find that.